# MS Access SQL Duplicate Rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ([Equipment List].ID) AS Expr1, [Job Assignments].Job
FROM [Equipment List] LEFT JOIN [Job Assignments] 
    ON [Equipment List].ID = [Job Assignments].EquipmentID;
```

In this query, the equipment ID is distinct if and only if I do not add the [Job Assignments].Job in the select statement. As soon as I do, I get many duplicates. The Job Assignments table has many jobs, but I am only interested in the one with the [Date Returned] blank or null. Any ideas how to accomplish this? I am using this as a report, so It gives me an error when I try to use inner sql queries. Also this is a simplified query, as the original has multiple selects. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: I am looking to select only one row from [Job Assignments] Table. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DISTINCT returns distinct combinations of all columns in the SELECT statement, which is why introducing a second column also introduces dupes.

It sounds like you can get away with a WHERE clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ([Equipment List].ID) AS Expr1, [Job Assignments].Job 
FROM [Equipment List] 
LEFT JOIN [Job Assignments] ON [Equipment List].ID = [Job Assignments].EquipmentID
WHERE [Job Assignments].[Date Returned] IS NULL
```

You can't have a "blank" date, so if you're seeing blanks then chances are you're not using a datetime type to store your date - in this case, you'll need to say:

```
WHERE COALESCE([Job Assignments].[Date Returned], '') = ''
```

Edit: Latest solution based on comments below:

```
;WITH LatestJobs
AS
(SELECT     ja.EquipmentID, ja.Job,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY EquipmentID 
                                ORDER BY [Date Returned] DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM        [Job Assignments] AS ja)

SELECT      el.ID AS EquipmentID, 
            lj.Job
FROM        [Equipment List] AS el
LEFT JOIN   LatestJobs AS lj ON el.ID = lj.EquipmentID
            AND lj.RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: very good, Thank you however the [Equipment List].ID and [Job Assignments].EquipmentID should be unique. How would I go about doing that? Shouldn't the Distinct [Equipment List].ID only select those IDs that are distinct in both tables?

Comment: It selects distinct combinations of fields.  For instance, if you had a row where [Equipment List].ID = 12 & [Job Assignments].Job = 27, and a second row the the same values, only one would be returned.  If, however, you had a third result with [Equipment List].ID = 12 & [Job Assignments].Job = 28, you would get two rows - one for Job 27, and one for Job 28.  Even if the Equipment ID was the same for both rows, it will still be returned both times, because the COMBINATION is unique.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense. How would I go about getting only the latest job? I just want one of the combination based on the EquipmentID. So for teach EquipmentID I want just one [Job Assignments].Job

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you on?  2000?  2005?  2008?

Comment: Check the main post then - I added a new snippet that should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow that is one complicated query. The problem is that I am using MS Access and it will not take this. I'm sorry to bother you but do you know how to convert this into an MS Access query?

Comment: I thought you said you were using SQL Server 2005?

Comment: Aaron sorry for the confusion, I am running this query on the access database, which is connected through odbc to a sql server 2005.

Answer (score 0):

What are the datatypes of each field on the select? If it is longchar(sql) or memo(in access) you will not be able to use the distinct function.